# How do I share a java game?

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

I created a simple 2D game in java and would like my friends to be able to play it - what is the easiest way to deploy this game or perhaps embed it in an html page?

I looked into Java Web Start but many of the steps are confusing me: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html

Any help would be appreciated!  Is there a way I could just convert my application into a jar file and share it with my friends?  If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: i am using eclipse ide

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the left in eclipse
2. right click the project you are working on
3. click export
4. open the java folder
5. select runnable jar file and click next
6. have the launch configuration be whatever class has the main method
7. if you are using external libraries select package required libraries, otherwise choose extract required libraries
8. change export location to where you want it to be
9. click finish
10. profit

Comment: i followed these steps, and it created two folders within the export location, one named "myproject" and another named "META-INF", but either way there is still no way to run this project.

Comment: does it export as a jar file or as two folders?

Comment: it exports as two folders - how do i make it export as a jar file?

Comment: when you change the export location does it end in FileName.jar